I spent a term abroad in Copenhagen. I'm US citizen. I will return to US after term .then 2 months later I go to England for 5 weeks can I enter UK?
I spent a term abroad in Copenhagen since January getting a residency visa for school. I'm a US citizen. I will return to the US after the term in May, then 2 months later I will go to England for 5 weeks. Can I enter the UK if I have been in Copenhagen for the last few months?

Are you going to the UK as a Visitor? As the UK is not ( & never has been) part of Schengen, provided you meet the Visitor Rules you should be OK.         https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor

What does having been in Copenhagen have to do with entering the UK?

To summarize what has been answered in the comments, the UK is not part of the Schengen area and so spending time in Copenhagen has no bearing on your ability to enter the UK.
